# Output subset of images from FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

With FFMPEG I can kick out an .MP4 as a sequence of images:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec png output%04d.png
```

output001.png, output002.png, output003.png, output004.png etc.

However, I'd like to just convert a small part of that whole .MP4, say between 00:07 and 00:10, producing 3 seconds images (30fps * 3 = 90 images)

Sort of like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec png -start 07 -end 10 output%04d.png
```

(Where start and end represent the sequence Start and End times)

Is this possible with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 7 -t 3 -i input.mp4 output%04d.png
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 7 -to 10 output%04d.png
```

(this is slower)

Comment: That totally worked! What's the syntax for if the starting point is over the minute mark? Do you need to specify it in seconds still like 67?

Comment: Sure. Or `1:07`